# Getting String to display with calculation Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm a beginner in Javascript and I'm trying to get a string of selections to display simultaneously as a calculation is performed on the number of boxes checked (as a price). I'd like to use vanilla Javascript for this.

HTML

```
<h3> Select Toppings </h3> 
        <form id="pizza-meat">
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Italian Sausage">Italian Sausage<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Bacon">Bacon<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Canadian Bacon">Canadian Bacon<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Meatballs">Meatballs<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Ham">Ham<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Grilled Chicken">Grilled Chicken<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Beef">Beef<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Pork">Jalapeno Peppers <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Slim Jims"> Slim Jims <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="meat"  onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Salami"> Salami <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Anchovies"> Anchovies <br>
    </form> 

    <output id="result">Meat Price: <span id="selected2">0</span></output>

    Meat: <output id="pizzaMeat"> </output>
```

Javascript

```
var selectedElm = document.getElementById('selected2');

function pizzaMeatPrice () {
  selectedElm.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=meat]:checked').length*0.25;
}

document.querySelectorAll("input[name=meat]").forEach(i=>{
 i.onclick =() => pizzaMeatPrice();
});

function meatOnPizza() {
  var meat = document.getElementById("pizza-meat");
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < meat.length; i++) {
    if (meat[i].checked) {
      txt = txt + meat[i].value + ", ";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("pizzaMeat").value = txt;
}
```

For some reason, the string of meats won't display anything. Ideally, it would display:

Bacon, Pork, Salami,    (any other selections)

but for whatever reason, it doesn't display.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just call meatOnPizza(); into pizzaMeatPrice function.

Comment: My Javascript is in a separate file and linked to the HTML document. It works with earlier functions (with radio buttons) but not with the checked boxes.

Comment: Have you tried this ?

Comment: I think this is what Maximiliano Poggio posted below, it doesn't calculate nor return the string.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to this one

```
function pizzaMeatPrice () {
      selectedElm.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=meat]:checked').length*0.25;
      meatOnPizza();
    }
```

Comment: This function doesn't display the price nor the selection of the user.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var selectedElm = document.getElementById('selected2');

function pizzaMeatPrice () {
  selectedElm.innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('input[name=meat]:checked').length*0.25;
  meatOnPizza();
}

document.querySelectorAll("input[name=meat]").forEach(i=>{
 i.onclick =() => pizzaMeatPrice();
});

function meatOnPizza() {
  var meat = document.getElementById("pizza-meat");
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < meat.length; i++) {
    if (meat[i].checked) {
      txt = txt + meat[i].value + ", ";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("pizzaMeat").value = txt;

}
```

```html
<h3> Select Toppings </h3> 
        <form id="pizza-meat">
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Italian Sausage">Italian Sausage<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Bacon">Bacon<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Canadian Bacon">Canadian Bacon<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Meatballs">Meatballs<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Ham">Ham<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Grilled Chicken">Grilled Chicken<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Beef">Beef<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Pork">Jalapeno Peppers <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Slim Jims"> Slim Jims <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="meat"  onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Salami"> Salami <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="meat" onclick="meatOnPizza()" value="Anchovies"> Anchovies <br>
    </form> 

    <output id="result">Meat Price: <span id="selected2">0</span></output><br>

    Meat: <output id="pizzaMeat"> </output>
```

How abaout this. Codes are working.

Comment: That works to display the string! However, it isn't calculating the price in the browser (using notepad++ and chrome) but it does calculate in JSFiddle.